# Allow value to be a function so we have the same API as useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I started analyzing useLocalStorage hook from [https://usehooks-ts.com/](https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-local-storage) and I am wondering why they are actually allowing value to be a function in `setValue` ? There is a comment "Allow value to be a function so we have the same API as useState" but I don't really understand it. In what case value would be a function? Could anyone explain it for me?

```
 try {
      // Allow value to be a function so we have the same API as useState
      const newValue = value instanceof Function ? value(storedValue) : value

      // Save to local storage
      window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(newValue))

      // Save state
      setStoredValue(newValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a "[functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)":

> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a function to `setState`. The function will receive the previous value, and return an updated value.

It is especially interesting if you update the state value asynchronously, while the current value *may* have changed in the meantime, and your final update must account for this new change.